# Grep xcov result into variable at fastfile

Tags: grep, code-coverage, fastlane

I'm using fastlane but I don't want to use xcov slack feature, I'm compiling all the info onto the same slack notification further sent.

```
lane :run_my_stuff do

xcov(project: "my-app.xcodeproj", 
     scheme: "my_scheme",
     output_directory: "xcov_output",
     only_project_targets: true)

$coverage=sh("grep \"(\d+.\d+\%)\"")

slack(message: "",
      success: true,
      slack_url: "https://hooks.slack.com/services/xxxxxxxx...",
      default_payloads: [],
      link_names: true,
      attachment_properties: {
            fields: [{
                      title: "Coverage",
                      value: $coverage
                     }
            ]
      })
end
```

This doesn't work but I believe it shows what I'm trying to achieve. I also tried to use:

```
$coverage=sh("cat xcov_report/index.html | grep '\d\+.\d\+\%' | head -1")
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was wrong w/ my code. Several things (sigh)

1. There is no need for dollar sign

```
coverage=sh("cat xcov_output/index.html | grep '\\d\\+.\\d\\+\\%' -o | head -1")
```

2. The folder in which I was wasn't the same I thought. So I changed the output path to `fastlane/xcov_output`
3. The escaping at the regular expression was not enough. So I doubled it

End

```
xcov(project: "my-app.xcodeproj",
       scheme: "MOCK",
       output_directory: "fastlane/xcov_output",
       only_project_targets: true)

release_notes=sh("git tag -l --format='%(contents)' $(git describe $(git rev-list --tags --max-count=1))")

coverage=sh("cat xcov_output/index.html | grep '\\d\\+.\\d\\+\\%' -o | head -1")

slack(message: " b(#{number_of_commits}) <@XXXXX>",
       success: true,
       slack_url: "https://hooks.slack.com/services/...",
       default_payloads: [],
       link_names: true,
       attachment_properties: {
           fields: [
               {
                   title: "Release notes",
                   value: release_notes
               },
               {
                   title: "Environment",
                   value: environment.capitalize
               },
               {
                   title: "Coverage",
                   value: coverage
               }
           ]
       }
   )
```